# Bootstrap two equal height div inside a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap and trying.

I need a pattern as follows

[image]

How ca we split the div's vertically with two equal divs ?

In horizondal we can do that by `col-md-6`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does setting a fixed height work for you?

Comment: please share a fiddle or bootply

Comment: if you could setup a fiddle for what you already have, you will get the exact answer, quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your browser support you could always use CSS3 Flexbox

I did a quick demo here of what you're after.

http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/LCbIx

```
.container {
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: gray;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 750px;
}
```

All the flexbox settings are set on the containing element and it does the rest from there on in.

A good article about FlexBox can be found here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

> Bootstrap mainly focuses on **WIDTH**, thus to my knowledge there are
>   no special **classes** to make two div's of equal height.

You can do it by specifying `height:/* value in px */;` in the `<div>`'s styling !

```
<div class="container"> /*Grid Layout*/
<div class="row testdiv">/*row cuts of 15px margin of left&right*/
</div>
<div class="row testdiv">
</div>
</div>
```

Now the **CSS :**

```
.testdiv{
height:400px;/*or some other value*/
}
```

A `class` selector is used to affect the styling of both div's at the same time !

Comment: why so complicated answer (at least complicated for a bootstrap beginner) for a simple question?

Comment: Just added a class to both rows and thats complicated ?

Comment: your answer does not highlight the exact workaround for the problem. just show him the working code instead of teaching him how bootstrap's grid system works. he has a concrete problem, so provide a concrete solution. this answer can be simplified much more.

Answer (score 1):

add two div as follows

> ```
> <div class="container-fluid mainbg">
>  <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-12 div1">.col-md-12</div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-12 div2">.col-md-12</div>
>  </div>
> </div>
> ```

Some css code to include

> .mainbg{
>       background:grey;
>       padding:10px; }
>
> .div1{
>       background:red; }
>
> .div1, .div2{
>       height:100px;
>       line-height:100px;
>       font-size:50px; }
>
> .div2{
>          text-align:center;
>        }

Comment: this doesn't guarantee that the heights are the same for both `.row`

Comment: then complete you answer by including your css code too. you are missing them in the answer.

Comment: still looks bad. add those classes to html too. there is no `.div1` in your html for example.

Comment: i would go like giving `.mainbg` some height, and then giving `.div1, .div2` 50% of height. this way it will be more flexible.

Comment: thats also a solution zafar there are many ways to get things done deoending on what user needs :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use css tables to achieve equal-height rows

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/112683)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="one">DIV1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="two">DIV2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
.container-fluid
{
  height: 200px; /* whatever you need */
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.one,.two
{
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
} 
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
```